# Show hide elements based on cookie value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

A novice in javascript, jquery. trying to show hide elements on a html with this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($.cookie() == "NAV1") {
        $(".sys, .Indiv").show();
        $(".pb, .er").hide();
    } 
    else if ($.cookie() == "NAV2") {
        $(".pb, .Indiv").show();
        $(".sys, .er").hide();  
    } 
    else if ($.cookie() == "NAV3") {
        $(".er").show();
        $(".sys, .pb, .Indiv").hide();
    }       
});
```

Comment: can you share your markup and a brief about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Did you include the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)?

Comment: am passing 3 different cookies from 3 pages
from page1: NAV1; from page2: NAV2; from page3: NAV3; 

the above code is in page4

The objective: Depending on from which page the user navigates in, the relevant elements shoud show or hide
For instance: User comes in from Page1, then ".sys, .Indiv" should show, ".pb, .er" should hide and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give name of specific cookie that you want to retrieve eg `($.cookie('navID')` where **navID** is name of cookie that you are using to set value.

```
if ($.cookie('navID') == "NAV1") {
    $(".sys, .Indiv").show();
    $(".pb, .er").hide();
} 
else if ($.cookie('navID') == "NAV2") {
    $(".pb, .Indiv").show();
    $(".sys, .er").hide();  
} 
else if ($.cookie('navID') == "NAV3") {
    $(".er").show();
    $(".sys, .pb, .Indiv").hide();
}
```

`$.cookie(`) gives collection of all cookies in form of object

**EDIT 1**

You need to check whether particular cookie has been set with value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if ($.cookie('NAV1')) {
        $(".sys, .Indiv").show();
        $(".pb, .er").hide();
    } 
    else if ($.cookie('NAV2')) {
        $(".pb, .Indiv").show();
        $(".sys, .er").hide();  
    } 
    else if ($.cookie('NAV3')) {
        $(".er").show();
        $(".sys, .pb, .Indiv").hide();
    } 

});
```

**EDIT 2**

Create a single cookie say `$.cookie('PageID')` and set its value in different pages. Then check the value of this cookie on landing page i.e. page 4 which will tell you the source page.

page 1

```
$.cookie('PageID', 'NAV1'); //page 1
```

on page 2

```
$.cookie('PageID', 'NAV2'); //page 2
```

and on page 3

```
$.cookie('PageID', 'NAV3'); //page 3
```

Then on page 4 on load check value of this cookie

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($.cookie('PageID') == "NAV1") {
    $(".sys, .Indiv").show();
    $(".pb, .er").hide();
} 
else if ($.cookie('PageID') == "NAV2") {
    $(".pb, .Indiv").show();
    $(".sys, .er").hide();  
} 
else if ($.cookie('PageID') == "NAV3") {
    $(".er").show();
    $(".sys, .pb, .Indiv").hide();
} 

});
```

Comment: am passing 3 different cookies from 3 pages
from page1: NAV1; from page2: NAV2; from page3: NAV3; 

the above code is in page4

The objective: Depending on from which page the user navigates in, the relevant elements shoud show or hide
For instance: User comes in from Page1, then ".sys, .Indiv" should show, ".pb, .er" should hide and so on

Comment: you need to check whether cookie exists while landing on page 4. check edited answer

Comment: rather than using three different cookies , use one cookie and set its value depnding on the page from which you are landing to page 4 .. check edited answer

Comment: WOW, thanks a load, the EDIT 2 worked like a charm, made my day

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

$.cookie() reads all cookies. You must read specific cookie value.

`$.cookie('cookieName');` read cookie with name